# StringBuilder.AppendFormat Throws Exception

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, padding, stringbuilder

I have an instance of `StringBuilder` in my C# application wherein I would like certain lines to be padded with a varying number of spaces depending on the context.  My usage is very simple:

```
StringBuilder MyStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
MyStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0:" + this._padding + "}"); // <-- Exception thrown here
MyStringBuilder.AppendLine("My data.");
```

If `this._padding==10`, the resulting output should look something like this:

> ```
>      My data.
> ```

How can I pad my strings without resorting to using a for loop?  Thanks.

***ADDITIONAL INFO***

Exception: "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You need to provide both the format and the arguments in one call.
- To pad left you use `{0,10}`, not `{0:10}`.

Try this:

```
MyStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0," + this._padding + "}", "My Data");
```

There is also a `string.PadLeft` method that you could use.

```
MyStringBuilder.Append("My Data".PadLeft(this._padding));
```

Answer (score 4):

You never passed a parameter for `{0}` to refer to.

Answer (score 3):

`AppendFormat()` expects the data to format as additional argument:

```
MyStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0:" + this._padding + "}", "My data.");
```

Answer (score 2):

That seems a strange way of doing:

```
sb.Append(' ', this._padding).AppendLine("My Data");
```

Comment: +1 for the concatenation of Append Methods, great, wasnt aware of that

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
//  AppendFormat("{0:" + this._padding + "}");
    AppendFormat("{0:" + this._padding + "}", "");
```

A place-holder is holding a place for *something*.

> Exception: "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."

`0` is greater than or equal to zero but it in this case it was not *less* than the size of the argument list (`0` as well).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply write something like `MyStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}");` You must give the variable to be formatted by the format string, like `MyStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}", "My data");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use IEnumerable.Repeat to generate arbitrary numbers of the same string/char.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx

Answer (score -1):

A lame way of doing it, but should work

```
for(int i=0; i <this._padding; i++)
{
   MyStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}"," ");
}
```

_padding needs to be an int

Comment: I specifically stated in the OP that I did not want to use a for loop.